# Windows: downloading of a wmv file (is it stream)?

Tags: windows, download, mp3, streaming, media

Win7/x64.

I saw a website that containing a report.

http://www.dunatv.hu/gazdasag/varga_istvan_szerint_milliardok_hianyoznak.html

It is uses Windows Media Player plugin that I installed under Firefox, so I can see.

I want to convert this report to mp3 file. I found the url in the html.

http://80.249.172.28/video/2010_06/10110021957701.wmv

But this is not working. I don't found any streamer, or video downloader that can download this file. I can see only in browser.

I don't know what to do with it. Maybe I do wrong something.
I tried "Orbit", "Downloadhelper", "VLC Player", direct download from Firefox...
I got the feeling that I'm lama... :-)

Do you have any idea how can I do this? Is it stream? Or is it something another thing?

Thanks for your help:
  dd

Comment: That WMV you link to is a red herring. It's not a real WMV. Look inside it in notepad.  But try what Frank said and see if you can download the video, from that main page there.

Comment: It's a .WVX - Which is a standard Windows Media Audio/Video Playlist (you can see this by doing "Save Target As..."). Often it's referred to a Windows Media "Redirector" file.  Inside it will be the individual media file paths to play/download.  They probably just renamed it .WMV to keep people from getting nervous when they go to click it (oh no! a WVX??), or to make it work with existing code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install "[Internet Download Manager](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/)".

It has a plug-in, that automatically downloads hidden URLs (of video and audio) from the browser for you.

Once you download it, you can use [this service](http://www.mediaconverter.org) (mediaconverter.org) to convert it to your preferred format.

Comment: have you tested it on that WMV he included in his question?

Comment: yes. i opened that file myself, and only IDM picked up the file from the url he gave.

Comment: I installed IDM and FDM too, but they are also downloading only the vxw file. In this file I see only same location... I trying KMPLAYER to catch audio, but it is crashed...

Comment: Orbit Download manager can download this file automatically! :-)